# Is it normal for a motor to run at an amperage above the nameplate rating?

Tags: electrical

I installed a 220 volt motor with a fla nameplate rating of 6.9. When checking the lines when running under load I got a reading of 7.01 and 7.03. Is this normal for motor to run at a amperage above nameplate rating?

Comment: Though I am not quite sure how motors are compared to straight resistance, there definitely will be differences in current for any given motor depending on voltage. A 220V motor could, depending on the power supplied to the building and other factors, easily run anywhere between 208V and 240V - several % up or down. Your difference in current is < 2%. What voltage are you actually supplying to the motor?

Comment: In engineering, there is the concept of "tolerance". In most consumer items, a tolerance of 4% would be considered quite good. Is your measuring device that accurate? Is the motor causing any issues?

Comment: Is it a deep well pump or some sort of blower? it might need a touch more resistance to (counterintuitively, but that's how it works) bring the amperage down.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote reversed.

Comment: Measure the power. What is your actual AC power voltage?  What does the nameplate on the motor say?   Consumers toss around "110/220V" for historic reasons (like calling a nose tissue a "Kleenex" or calling a photocopy "Xerox").  But nameplates don't - they say reality.   (also, LOL at people who call it "110V" and then panic at more than 3% "voltage drop".  Um, 110V *is a 9% voltage drop from what power actually is*, so they're clearly tolerant of 9% drop.)

Comment: 234 volts to the pump

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application and the values you are measuring are within the normal variation in motors.

Be aware a change in voltage will also affect the actual current draw similarly the load on the the motor will affect the current draw

The closest single phase motor at these values is a 2HP , if the load is increased the draw will go up.

So in short there are many things that affect how much current the motor will draw and being within .13 amp I can just about guarantee you that your meter is not that accurate but it is not a big deal.

the motor overloads are normally set at 1.15% or 7.9amps for 10 seconds so there is nothing to worry about on a motor with a 6.9fla drawing 7.03amps indefinitely.

Comment: The meter inaccuracies are a big culprit and users rarely get them re-calibrated.+1...  good to see ya.